# Pascal arranging array, with a row number

Tags: arrays, pascal

```
type
  mas = array [1 .. 10000] of real;

var
  n: integer;
  a: mas;
  Rf: text;

Procedure Skaityti;
var
  i: integer;
  Df: text;
begin
  Assign(Df, 'duom1.txt');
  Reset(Df);
  Readln(Df, n);
  for i := 1 to n do
    Read(Df, a[i]);
  Close(Df);
end;

Procedure MinMax(var min, max, nrmin, nrmax, vid: real);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  min := a[1];
  max := a[1];
  nrmin := 1;
  nrmax := 1;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    if min > a[i] then
    begin
      min := a[i];
      nrmin := i;
    end;
    if max < a[i] then
    begin
      max := a[i];
      nrmax := i;
    end;
    vid := vid + a[i];
  end;
  vid := vid / n;
end;

var
  min, max, nrmin, nrmax, vid: real;

begin
  Skaityti;
  MinMax(min, max, nrmin, nrmax, vid);
  Assign(Rf, 'rez.txt');
  Rewrite(Rf);
  WriteLn(Rf, 'biggest amount     ', max:7:2, '   number ', nrmax:7:0);
  WriteLn(Rf, 'smallest  amount     ', min:7:2, '   number', nrmin:7:0);
  WriteLn(Rf, 'average amount       ', vid:7:2);
  WriteLn(Rf);
  WriteLn(Rf, 'number   amount');
  Close(Rf);
end.
```

This is the code and it Reads elements from a .txt file to an array, I created procedure to find biggest and smallest value of it. Now I need to create a procedure to write my array from biggest to smallest and a row number next to it. It should look something like this:

```
Row number       value
  5             1000000
  6             999999
  8             888888
```

and so on.. Any ideas ?

P.S. I can arrange that array to be from biggest to smallest but then the row numbers will mess up :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a record type with two fields, one for the value from the file and the other for the "row" number.

Change the array to be an array of that record type.

When reading the file in the for loop, assign the read value to the value field of the record and the for loop control variable value as the "row" number.

When you sort the array, you sort the records, thus keeping value and row together.

Comment: Hmm, we still haven't learned anything about record in school , any other ways ? I'll try to learn what's a record now too

Comment: No, I can't really think of any other (reasonable) way. A record structure is specifically invented to keep closely related data together. I believe you will find the concept quite simple in its basic form (which you need).

Comment: @Tom: I can. He could use two arrays, one for the reals and one for the indices. Swapping in one would mean swapping in the other too. Using records would of course be more natural and probably a lot better, but it *can* be done without them.